# Dell Perc 6i - Move cable to other port, keep Virtual Drive?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

Quick question.

I have a Dell Perc 6i RAID controller and need to move the port cable from A to B (cable length issues). Can I just move the connector over and keep the RAID? Or will I have to rebuild it as it is on a different port?

Basically I connected it to port 1 (left side) and simply want to move it to port 0 (right side). Will it keep the Virtual Drive intact if I just move it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply move it and the RAID controller will still find the VD. Hope this helps someone wondering the same thing!